# Why when i use a class in dart with equatable and just a list as property the copyWith method return the same object, same hascode

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

Im using bloc and it was working as expected but today i notice a strage behaviour when i was sending the same state (RefreshState) using copyWith, the state wasnt trigger after second call. then i did a test creating two objects and compared them but the result was they are the same object, very odd.

So why is this happen?, this is my class:

```
 class Model extends Equatable {
  final List<Product> mostBuyProducts;

  const Model({
    this.mostBuyProducts,
  });

  Model copyWith({
    List<Product> mostBuyProducts,
  }) =>
      Model(
        mostBuyProducts: mostBuyProducts ?? this.mostBuyProducts,
      );

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [
        mostBuyProducts,
      ];
}
```

and then i use the CopyWith method like (inside the bloc):

```
  Stream<State> _onDeleteProduct(OnDeleteProduct event) async* {
    state.model.mostBuyProducts.removeWhere((p) => p.id == event.id);

    var newMostBuyProducts = List<Product>.from(state.model.mostBuyProducts);

    final model1 = state.model;
    final model2 = state.model.copyWith(mostBuyProducts: newMostBuyProducts);

    final isEqual = (model1 == model2);

    yield RefreshState(
        state.model.copyWith(mostBuyProducts: newMostBuyProducts));
  }
```

isEqual return true :/

BTW this is my state class

```
@immutable
abstract class State extends Equatable {
  final Model model;
  State(this.model);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [model];
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect them not to be equal? You create a reference, newMostBuyProducts, to the mostBuyProducts property of state.model, then simply create a new instance with that property reference. They both have the same instance of List<Product> as the value of the only property that is used to determine equality.

Comment: it is suppose that copyWith creates a new object, or im wrong?

Comment: In your case copyWith does instantiate a new Model. But in _onDeleteProduct you're calling copyWith with the mostBuyProducts List from the original instance, so the new instance is being constructed with the same List. And in your implementation of the props property, mostBuyProducts is the only thing being compared when equality is being determined.

Comment: @DonR ok I understand that part, I understand that if I compare the two objects inside are the same by the list but I don't understand if  I use copyWith i supposed that the new object should be created with a new hascode  but is created with the same hascode, it is a normal behavior of 'equatable' ?

Comment: If you implement Equatable it explicitly creates the new object with the same hashcode: https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/equatable.
copyWith, as you've implemented it, simply creates a new instance and, since in your code you're passing it a reference to the same List, so the new instance is exactly the same as the original; you're not overriding the property in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes because lists are mutable. In order to detect a change in the list you need to make a deep copy of the list. Some methods to make a deep copy are available here : https://www.kindacode.com/article/how-to-clone-a-list-or-map-in-dart-and-flutter/

Using one such method in the solution below! Just change the copyWith method with the one below.

```
Model copyWith({
    List<Product> mostBuyProducts,
  }) =>
      Model(
        mostBuyProducts: mostBuyProducts ?? [...this.mostBuyProducts],
      );
```